# Can I open an RTE tag in a specific element with a button in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

By RTE tags I mean `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`, or `<s>` tags. I've been working on a RTE, and using jquery I can get the entire area to bold, but I want to be able to bold only a specific portion (think google docs, word, or any other text editor).

The mozilla site only had deprecated information, and inspecting elements on other sites (including this one) were no help to me.

I am trying to edit a `content-editable` `<div>` currently, although I'm open to switching to a text area if that works better.

```js
//my jquery for bolding the entire thing
var bolded = false;
$("#bold").on('click', function(){
    //access css of editor div, change status using a ternary
    $("#editor").css("font-weight", bolded ? this.value : 'bold');
    bolded = !bolded;
    //log for debugging
    console.log('clicked bold: ' + bolded);
});
```

```html
my HTML5 for the editor. Sectioned off for formatting purposes.
<section>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable="TRUE"></div>
</section>
```

My buttons are `id`'d as "bold", "itallic", "strike", and "underl", but I really just want to get one of them working so I can work from there.

---

***EDIT***
I realized that this question isn't as straightforward as I'd hoped. I have a `<div>`, and I would like to have multiple different formats inside of this `<div>`. The way I would do it logially is by inserting a `<b>` tag on the click of a button / keyboard command and then continuing to type from there, but I can't find any resources for it. Hope this clears that up.

---

***EDIT 2***
So as far as I can tell, the `document.execCommand()` still works but is predicted to be replaced by [Input Events Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/input-events-2/). I can't find any readable documentation for implementing this. Does anybody know how to do this?

---

Comment: Why don't you use styles instead of "RTE"?

Comment: "using jquery I can get the entire area to bold, but I want to be able to bold only a specific portion". Not understood: what's the difference between "entire area" and "specific portion". You define the area as to what among the tag, right? And how do you define the "specific portion"? Examples, please.

Comment: @HoRn RTE in this context stands for Rich Text Editor, sorry for the confusion.
Also: entire area is the `<div>` tag, whereas a specific portion is a word, character, or block of text inside of that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for current methodology (`document.execCommand('command')`):

Attaching a simple `onclick()` to the buttons works, where that `onclick` is a function that runs the aforementioned command with no particular focus:

```js
function format(command, value){
    //In use, "value" is left blank in order to do the current selection / no selection
    document.execCommand(command, false, value);
}
```

```html
    <button onclick="format('bold')"><strong>B</strong></button>
    <button onclick="format('italic')"><em>I</em></button>
```

Please note that this functionality WILL be deprecated, but no replacement has come up yet. When I know more, I will come back and edit this answer.